# How can I receive swipe gesture on my view while having it transparent?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm making a swipe gesture recogniser which receives swipes in particular `UIView` but I also want it to be transparent, making the `alpha=0` doesnt responds to swipes.

This is the code for adding the gesture:

```
@IBOutlet weak var swipeView: UIView!
let swipeRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    swipeRec.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipedView))
    swipeView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRec)
    swipeView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    swipeRec.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
}

func swipedView(){
    print("swiped")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the background color of the view to ClearColor rather than alpha to 0 should work.

```
swipeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```